# Stripe webhooks fail with null entry for parameter 'id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to integrate with [stripe.com](http://stripe.com) and webhooks are giving me an issue.

I've created a controller and an action to accept and parse the webhooks from stripe:

```
public class WebhooksController : AbstractController
{
    public JsonResult Stripe(int id)
    {
        // some parsing code
    }
}
```

This is routed via

```
routes.MapRoute("webhooks", "Financial/Webhooks/{action}/{id}", new { "Webhooks", "Index", id = "" }, new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers.Financial" });
```

I can hit this route fine from the browser or with

```
curl -i -H "Host: mydomain.com" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://{resolvedIP}/Financial/Webhooks/Stripe/4
```

However, when I try to fire the webhook from stripes dashboard using the "test webhook" feature, I get a 500:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Stripe(Int32)' in 'Drg.M3.Client.Controllers.Financial.WebhooksController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

According to one staff member in the stripe chatroom the webhooks are sent with something like this:

```
curl -i -H "Host: mydomain.com" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://{resolvedIP}/Financial/Webhooks/Stripe/4 -d '{big ol' json object}'
```

Why would a request with data fail at routing when one without the data goes through?

Comment: What's the type of that id on the receiving end ? Is it possible that it's some kind of a Guid and you're trying to pass in an empty string ?

Comment: The type is an `int`. In this example it's `4` (http://{ip}/Financial/Webhooks/Stripe/4).

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point inside of your Stripe method and see if it gets hit ? Also that id = "" in a default route just doesn't sit right with me with your ID being an INT

Comment: The action does not get hit. The default id of "" should be no different than id = (int?)null. As a matter of fact, MVC doesn't care what type the url segments are when routing only when invoking the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Turns out, that when MVC sees a content type of `application/json` it tries to auto bind the data to your action parameters.

Since the json object Stripe sends includes

```
{
  "id" : "evt_0000000000",
  ...
}
```

The `id` parameter was getting set to `evt_0000000000` instead of `4`.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC's automatic mapping of post data to controller action method parameter names isn't directly related to or limited to the application/json content type; the ASP.NET MVC url mapping engine does this mapping/parameter binding in a broad number of scenarios.